# How to call arbitrary amount of functions inside a function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.6

I would like to pass a specified amount of functions as arguments to the outermost function.
Inside the middle functions, I would like to call arbitrary amount of functions.
So the middle function is a group for the inner functions. Based on specific criteria the function groups may or may not be called.

In the example below the outermost function takes exactly 2 arguments, but the mid function shall take arbitrary amount of functions.

EG:

```
def al_func1():
    print('al 1')


def al_func2():
    print('al 2')


def ml_func1():
    print('ml 1')


def ml_func2():
    print('ml 2')


def function_to_connect(hostname: str, al, ml):
    print(f'Connecting to {hostname}')
    if 'al' in hostname:
        al
    elif 'ml' in hostname:
        ml


def call_al(*al_functs):
    al_functs


def call_ml(*ml_functs):
    ml_functs


function_to_connect('ipi-al', call_al(al_func1(), al_func2()), call_ml(
    ml_func1(), ml_func2()))
```

Basically it works, but regardless of the result of the "if" statement, the functions are always executed, and the order is not what I expect.

The output is:

```
al 1
al 2
ml 1
ml 2
Connecting to ipi-al
```

Thanks!

Comment: Because you don't pass the *functions* you **call them** and then pass the result... however, your `call_al` and `call_ml` functions do nothing... Note, `if 'al' in hostname: al` **doesn't do anything**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You were pretty close! What you need to learn here is

- Lambda functions
- Passing around functions without calling them
- How to iterate packed arguments (The * symbol)

I fixed your code for you, I think it's how you want it

```
def al_func1():
    print('al 1')


def al_func2():
    print('al 2')


def ml_func1():
    print('ml 1')


def ml_func2():
    print('ml 2')


def function_to_connect(hostname: str, al, ml):
    """
    This is the description for the function.

    :param str hostname: This is decription for 'hostname'
    :param function al: This is description for 'al'
    :param function ml: This is description for 'ml'
    """
    print(f'Connecting to {hostname}')
    if 'al' in hostname:
        al()
    elif 'ml' in hostname:
        ml()


def call_al(*al_functs):
    for func in al_functs:
        func()


def call_ml(*ml_functs):
    for func in ml_functs:
        func()


function_to_connect('ipi-al', lambda: call_al(al_func1, al_func2), lambda: call_ml(ml_func1, ml_func2))
```

Comment: You don't really need `lambda`, although you can use it in this case.

Comment: How do you pass the arguments without lambda?

Comment: A `lambda` expression just creates a function. You can create a function with a regular function definition statement and pass that

Comment: Thank you! This is what I wanted. Somehow the inner functions were executed even without the () but it did not work. By the way, can I specify the expected argument type to be a function? If so, how?

Comment: What would the syntax for that be @juanpa.arrivillaga?

Comment: There are many ways do define the type of arguments, I prefer to use `reStructuredText, or reST`. I can edit the `function_to_connect` function to show you @Istvan

Comment: @Mandera, please :)

Comment: I did when I wrote that haha, but perhaps you want it to raise an error if it's not a function?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the functions in, you put the "()" in there, which calls the function.

How to fix this:

- Remove the "()" at the end of the inputs, this runs the function
- Add "()" at the end of the functions, this will actually call the function and run it

Comment: @Mandera you do not need to know lambda or '*', they are for more advanced programming